# Set limit integers to JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, setbounds

How to set a limit to the input for user, I mean that the user can input only like 2 or 4 integers and no more.

Code:

```
 JLabel dateD = new JLabel("| Date  Day:");
 dateD.setBounds(170,270, 120, 25);

 dateDD = new JTextField();
 dateDD.setBounds(235,270, 20, 25);
```

Comment: Don't use `setBounds()` to set the size/locaton of components. Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I KNOW , you are not the first person who told me to use LayoutManager I need to use this method.... and question is how to make fixed INT with this method that I have used.......(((

Comment: So why do you continue to ask for help if you ignore the advice given?

Comment: I ask how to make fixed input with this way if it not possible using this method just say it THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE that's all what I ask...

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. You have been told it is posssible and you have been give the code to use. All you have to do is download the code from the tutorial and add it to your program.

Answer (score 1):

Using `DocumentFilter` should sort you out, create the filter as follows :-

```
class MaximumCharacters extends DocumentFilter {

        private int maxLength;

        public MaximumCharacters() {
            maxLength = 10; // The number of characters allowed
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
                AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (maxLength > 0
                    && fb.getDocument().getLength() + string.length() <= maxLength) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

            if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() - length) <= maxLength)
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    }
```

Then you set the `DocumentFilter` to your `JTextField` component as follows :-

```
((AbstractDocument) dateDD.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MaximumCharacters());
```

Comment: +1 for the DocumentFilter. See the Swing tutorial [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to use DocumentFilter?

Comment: -1, I originally upvoted for the suggestion to use a DocumentFilter, which is the correct approach to solve the problem. Instead you posted code extending a Document, which is NOT the preferred approach. Its is also confusing since the code has nothing to do with the suggestion to use a DocumentFilter.

Comment: @DenisNurasy, then you obvsiously didn't read the tutorial link I provided, since it includes working code and explanations about the code.

Comment: I have read, I just can't get this.... can't visualise how this method works this is the problem, and that's why I asked this question up here....

Comment: I don't know how you expect us to help. The tutorial provides working code for the DocumentFilter. It show the 4-5 lines of code needed to add the filter to the text field. It also explains the concept of a DocumentFilter. You haven't stated what it is that you don't understand. Did you even download the code and try it? If so then why didn't you post an SSCCE showing what you did?

Comment: @camickr thank you for the comments, i have revised my answer

Answer (score 0):

For the above answer below is a Utility method I have created to deal with above situations -

```
    /**
     * Method installNumericMaximumCharacters.
     * 
     * @param document
     *            AbstractDocument
     * @param numberofChars
     *            int
     */
    public static void installNumericMaximumCharacters(
            AbstractDocument document, final int numberofChars) {
        document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                    String string, AttributeSet attr)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                try {
                    if (string.equals(".")
                            && !fb.getDocument()
                                    .getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())
                                    .contains(".")) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
                        return;
                    }
                    Double.parseDouble(string);
                    if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + string.length() <= numberofChars) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
                    } else {
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                    String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                try {
                    if (text.equals(".")
                            && !fb.getDocument()
                                    .getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())
                                    .contains(".")) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attrs);
                        return;
                    }
                    Double.parseDouble(text);
                    int l = fb.getDocument().getLength() - length
                            + text.length();
                    if (length > 0) {
                        fb.getDocument().remove(offset, length);
                    }
                    if (l <= numberofChars) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attrs);

                    } else {
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The method is bit self explanatory. When ever a change occurs on the `Document` it will evoke the `DocumentFilter`. Beware that you cannot `setText()` the same `Document`. You will have to use the `FilterBypass` object for it.